# onCreateView() in fragment not called and showing black screen

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm creating and placing a Fragment like this:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(getApplicationContext(), item.getFragmentClass().getName());

ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, selectedNavItem);
ft.commit();
```

Until I migrated from Eclipse to Android Studio everything was OK. But after migration my splashscreen (which is an activity with fragment too) is running but when I switch to mainactivity with calling the fragment like above - it sometimes works and sometimes not - it calls the `onCreate()` in Fragment but **not** the `onCreateView()` and just stops on showing a black screen.

Maybe there are some problems with the including of libraries?

Here is my build.gradle with dependencies

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87')
    compile ('com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.3')
    compile ('com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3')
    compile ('com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.1.0')
    compile ('com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1')
    compile ('com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar')
    compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.0')
    compile (project(':libs:SlidingMenuLibrary'))
    compile (project(':libs:SwipeToDismissUndoList-master'))
}
```

Some help would be very appreciated, because I'm really desperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was really in the dependencies. The cause was some kind of bug in google play services (google analytics), that was causing that a thread was stopped and could not load the fragment. So I just downgraded the google play services version and it was working again.